# how to run any api which having a captcha on postman platform

Tags: python, json

I'm getting error about captcha based on url i am unable to see the captcha, is there any method to show the captcha. i want any suggestion to get that captcha visible and let my url run.

Comment: Hello. What is your code ? What have you tried ? What is the exact error ? Any stacktrace ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to display CAPTCHA on Postman. CAPTCHA is designed to prevent automated systems (like Postman) from accessing the API and is meant to be displayed and solved by a human. You'll need to manually access the API through a web browser to solve the CAPTCHA before making the API request.